# How does a user with 529 rep points edit a question?

Tags: discussion, reputation, edits

I'm referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531557/does-hadoop-support-a-holodeck-tag-closed) question, which may have been deleted by now.

I thought something like 2000 points were needed.

Comment: Ok, I see, if it's just tags, *I could have done that* (on SO), and I have in the past ... but blimey, *is that the time??* My brain must have stopped working.

Comment: Of all the things wrong with that post, you were curious about the *tags*?? :)

Comment: @Bill, no, if I had been curious about the tags, I might have realised *I* could have changed 'em.

Comment: Looks like this for archival reference: http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/6310/richmedit.png

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That particular user simply edited tags, which anyone is allowed to do at **500 rep**. Admittedly, it's not clear until you actually view the edit details, but he would *not* be allowed to edit the actual content at that rep. [The FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) details all the rep levels for perform various actions.

Answer (score 4):

You only need [500 reputation to edit tags](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation), which is what the user did. If you to the [revision list](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1531557/list) (click on the edited link), it will show you what users have made what changes.